# Can't get connection from JDBC

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I have this class on Android Studio:

```
@SuppressLint("NewAPI")
public void Connect() throws Exception {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    connection = null;
    String S_url = null;
    String driver = null;
    try {
        driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        S_url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                + pass + ";";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(S_url);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Connection getConnection() {
    return connection;
}
```

It's used to connect to my sql server database. Here is a problem, I can't get a connection from this class to use for PreparedStatement eventhough I can connect to my database.

I tried this code on Eclipse and it run perfectly:

My friend run this project on his Android Studio and it also work.

Edit:

This is an example:

```
public class Account_Control {
Connection connect;

// CONNECT DATABASE
public Account_Control(Connection connection) {
    this.connect = connection;
}


public boolean CheckUsername(String username) throws Exception {
    try {
        PreparedStatement query = connect.prepareStatement("select Username from Account where Username = '" + username + "'");
        ResultSet rs = query.executeQuery();
```

When i call this class on my MainActivity

```
private DatabaseConnection db;
private Account_Control account_control;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    db = new DatabaseConnection();
    try {
        db.Connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    account_control = new Account_Control(db.getConnection());
```

db.getConnection() is not working and it return a null account_control

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.haitr.planed_12062016/com.example.haitr.planed_12062016.LoginActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.PreparedStatement java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Check my edit dude

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of the exception. Sidenote: don't use terms like "dude", they are usually considered disrespectful or even offensive, and the person you are addressing might not even be male.

Comment: Share the stacktrace of the exception which will give idea about the exact error.

Comment: Thank Mark, i will notice this. Edited my post

Comment: Your English is not so bad, but please follow [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) quick checklist.